# solution for double text in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

```
private function getBrandIdFromName($brandName){
        $brand = Brand::query()->where('slug',$brandName)->first();
        
        if($brand){
            return $brand->id;
        }else{
            $newBrand = [
                'name'=>$brandName,
                'is_active'=>"1",
                'meta'=>[
                    'meta_title'=>null,
                    'meta_description'=>null,
                ]
            ];
            $brand = Brand::create($newBrand);
            return $brand->id;
        }
    }
```

this is my code when i import one text "nike" its working well. but when i import 2 text like "nike world" its importing text "nike world" again and again when i import text again. please do help if anyone has solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are querying on the `slug` property, while you are creating a brand with that brandname via the `name` property.

Also, you should be able to clean this code up a lot using `firstOrCreate()` like so:

```php
public function getBrandIdFromName($brandName) {
    return Brand::query()->firstOrCreate([
        'name' => $brandName
    ], [
        'is_active' => 1,
        'meta' => [
            'meta_title' => null,
            'meta_description' => null,
        ]
    ])->id;
}
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models

Comment: slug is column in 'brand' and name is column in 'brand translation' table both are different - @Flame

Comment: i think problem is with ->first() because it checking and importing fine for single text "nike" but importing again and again double word "hello nike"  @Flame

Comment: then why are you using the `Brand` class twice? it refers to the `brands` table

Comment: any modification in my code to import brand once.. if exist already then assign id .... otherwise create newone and assign id - @Flame

Comment: I have no clue what you are saying

Comment: for 1 word "nike " its checking if exist then assigning id to it if not then create nike brand and assigning id to it.. but, for 2 word " hello nike" even though it exist it creating new brand  - @Flame

Comment: it has nothing to do with a double word. A simple `WHERE "string"` will work irregardless if there is a space or not. The only thing that could play an issue is the collation of the database/table, which may or may not take case-sensitivity into account.

Comment: what i have to do then any changes in code or db? -@Flame